# What's the story with this user?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, trolling

I refer you to one user's exceptionally exciting life:

> [Jan 17](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/83144/1187): Gets fired by an intoxicated boss, but just went back to
>   work anyway to find out he has a new manager
>
> [Jan 26](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/83796/1187): Wasted a lot of time at work making an inappropriate
>   video about themselves as a "joke" for their new manager
>
> [Feb 9](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/84715/1187): Their car gets towed. They're running late on an important
>   project. They have night classes. They want to work less hours at work
>   because of of all these events.
>
> [Feb 10](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/84806/1187): Work presentation goes disastrously when
>   executives start grilling a junior employee (Hans) about stuff that
>   they would know that he wouldn't know
>
> [Feb 22](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/85476/1187): Hey, turns out I've actually been dating my new boss's
>   daughter! Oops!
>
> [Feb 22](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/45402/3836): My bike is broken. I have to use my bike a lot because I
>   don't have a car. Except I found out I was dating my boss's daughter
>   when I used my broken car to drop her off...
>
> [Feb 23](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/76516/1088): Guess what! I've been sitting on half a million dollars
>   of GM Stock for 10 years! Except it's actually worthless. Woe be to
>   me!
>
> [Feb 27](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/17392): I guess I'm going to sell my house now. Except someone
>   took a shit on the bed during my open house! And spilled orange soda
>   everywhere!
>
> [Mar 16](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/87157/1187): I cost my company $64,000 because I messed up my
>   booking. I don't have a phone which is why this happened, but somehow
>   even though my phone was broken I was able to date someones daughter
>   AND organise an open home to try an sell my house! Should I take out a 2nd mortgage on the house I'm trying to sell to pay them back?

There's a few (not many, but a few) inconsistencies in the stories, but I just cannot believe that a single person has undergone so many extreme events in such a short period of time.

Normally I wouldn't care too much about someone making such an elaborate story, but in this case I feel that they are seriously wasting a *lot* of people's time on here.

Comment: There's also the deleted law.se post about a bizarre chocolate factory accident.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Someone's been channeling their inner Willie Wonka..?

Comment: Yeah, but he's an *entertaining* troll!! :P

Comment: @BradC My concern is that they are getting so much attention to their questions that they are wasting a lot of people's time. If there wasn't so much time wasting going on, I wouldn't care.

Comment: Do we have a rule these questions need to be based on real events? If the questions are valid, I see no issue. Whoopee, they earned some reputation, that's going to help them in the future to do what? The user has bought some serious discussion to the workplace meta without any issues. I would leave the user be.

Comment: @Draken Eh, exaggerated could-never-happen-in-real-life hypotheticals fall more into "fun to discuss" than "this is practical advice that someone might someday need"

Comment: @BradC The questions posted on workplace so far seem to be quite valid, some of the other stack exchange's questions I would argue that they are a bit odd. But the questions here are things that can happen, true not the same person, but the advice is suitable for several people.

Comment: @MarkHenderson On another note, you might want to post about this on Stack Exchange meta (If you feel something should be done about this user), not sure how much coverage you would get here. Since the user has been doing their interesting questions across multiple stack exchanges

Comment: @Draken Fair point re: meta. I posted it here because this is where most of the time has been sunk. The thing is, I'm not entirely sure that some of these situations _would_ apply, given how... contrived they are.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Moleman

Comment: see also: [Should anything be done about a user posting fake questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/168)

Comment: The main problem I see with this is that some of the... situations described are rather contrived. That means that answers tend to be less generally useful and quite specific to the bizarre situation imagined by the OP. The [latest](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87157) question is a good example of that, particularly with how he's channelling answers by suggesting ways to react. But at the same time the question is well written and things like "I've thought of this but what are my options" and "how can I approach this?" are things I love to see in questions. A tricky situation.

Comment: I don't know. I can think of not one, but two (at *least*) people I know in real life whose personal timelines would make the misadventures of Mr. Moleman look rather mundane and unremarkable.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about

Comment: Fwiw the first (Jan 17) and most recent (Mar 16) events are believable. In fact the last one happened to me and I had a similar emotional roller coaster when I realised the problem. I've even given talks at meetups about it. But everything in between has the taste of absurdity.

Comment: This user is totally gaming us for reputation points.  The first one I would buy, but the rest...come on....

Comment: Thanks everyone, but this is not for some internet points as I can't exchange them for anything. It appears I have a following as well, though some people are rather upset. Yes, not all of these events happened in chronological order. Some of them happened on the same day as I posted and because I had such good responses, I shared other questions to see if I did the right thing in hopes others will look for them when they have similar situations.

Comment: if memory serves a while ago at Programmers there was a user who exploited HNQ by posting reworded versions of old popular questions. I think they dropped this habit after discovering that community learned about their trick

Comment: it's not wasted time if you're thinking of how to resolve a problem and exercising your intellect, and therefore not currently engaged in surfing more dodgy sites.

Comment: @HansMoleman good point regarding the fact that you cannot exchange them, but that doesn't mean they don't mean anything.  Part of the attraction of the stack is to help others while building your reputation.  I will be much more careful in terms of whose questions I spend my time on.  That's really all that can be done.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm confused, how does the boat question relate to this one?

Comment: @DavidK I guess [this answer over there relates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14493/165773): "it was featured on the podcast... This caused the question, which was performing poorly, to get a number of very good answers. Unfortunately, Jeff later learned that it was a joke question, deleted it, and posted on the blog asking users to refrain from posting questions like these in the future..." (given that at the moment of close "$64,000" question was firmly sitting at #1 in HNQ list the analogy feels quite close)...

Comment: ...[Trouble With Popularity](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7525/31260), business as usual

Comment: Something I've been mulling over is the importance of preserving the integrity of the Workplace as a helpful resource. While these types of questions might be amusing, the point of The Workplace isn't to amuse but to help people. I'd much rather see a site that is "boring" but helpful than full of questions like these that are entertaining but useless. And let's be honest, most of the questions that make a list like this are very, _very_ specific to the asker at best.

Comment: @enderland if memory serves [jmac](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7945/jmac) was also mulling about this when he was "just" a Workplace moderator. Incidentally his mulling seem to be stopped after he became a salaried employee of Stack Exchange. That could probably make an interesting (and _real_, not fake) Workplace question

Comment: see also: [Why was this question about handling the fallout a crass joke deleted?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4415/168) "several questions asked within the past few weeks had all been created by the same person, running multiple accounts and creating these scenarios - and associated "personalities" to go with them - for the purpose of trolling the community here..."

Comment: It seems to me like just answering the questions as though they are genuine is both more interesting and more likely to help someone in the future who actually does have a similar problem than trying to dig into their veracity, assuming each individual question is at least somewhat plausible.

Comment: @Casey this approach has already tried before: "we discovered that these posts... truly _start to drown out everything else on the site_... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power..." ([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Comment: given the bizarre nature of real life, disbelief is poor indicator of truth

Comment: @gnat I disagree; it seems to me that that's describing a different problem -- letting people ask whatever kind of questions they want.  But here we're talking about whether to delete questions that would definitely be in-scope if they were genuine over doubts over their veracity.  It just does not seem analogous to allowing "what's your favorite programming language?" kind of questions.

Comment: @Casey do you believe that real "boring" workplace issues have any chance to compete against _plausible inventions_. Day 1: slept with my manager, now they want to promote me, what do I do. Day 2: had sex in office toilet and colleague noticed, how to save my career. Day 3: lost million dollars when riding on my bike to work presentation, my whole life is on stake now.

Comment: I think a more interesting question to ask is why this elaborate troll has been so successful. What does that say about the sort of questions we're accepting?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition even when we don't accept them this doesn't really help because system is designed in a way that allows troll questions gain enough upvotes and views before close. See eg [At smaller sites, penalize hot questions having 3-4 close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237391/165773) (feature request that hangs ignored for more than 2 and half years now

Comment: Anyone willing to volunteer to go over to the Movies and TV Stack and ask an identification question based on these stories? That's a lot of creative juice spent on getting SE rep. I can't see myself trying to invent all these stories from scratch.

Comment: @gnat Not only do I believe that, I believe that there are people genuinely out there with whatever plausible "crazy" question someone posts and it's in keeping with the purpose of the site to allow such questions to be answered for their benefit down the road.

Comment: @Casey history of two other Stack Exchange sites has shown that things don't work this way (SO and Programmers). "The stuff spreads like kudzu..."

Comment: @gnat Again, I reject your claim that these situations are analogous.  It's hard to even imagine what an analogous question on SO would look like, given the nature of the site.

Comment: @Casey one example was referred just few comments ago ([boat programming](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/whats-the-story-with-this-user?noredirect=1#comment12021_4410), it even made it into meme). Hard to imagine, that's for sure: SO got rid of entertaining questions 7 or 8 years ago. If you're interested [a bit of this ancient history is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: ...last time I remember attempt at entertaining question at SO was over 3 years ago. It got wildly popular, caused much meta drama and was rather quickly deleted, see [Dealing with “Find out who's going to buy the croissants”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190106/165773)

Comment: This won't be a popular comment, but: Q: Why Workplace.SE has relatively many persistent fake-question writers? A: Because Workplace.SE's behaviour creates them. Some call it the most un-friendly "community" on SE...

Comment: I don't know, I kinda love this guy. The only troublesome part is that most of the stories are so dramatic that people are expressing genuine sympathy and feelbads.

Comment: @gnat How is "how do I prepare for programming at sea" an on-topic question for SO, even if it's a sincere question?  Again, the difference here is that these questions are on-topic and would be totally fine if they were true, and in isolation they're not totally implausible.

Comment: @deviantfan I'm genuinely curious.  What is the basis for your comment.  I've personally found this one of the more welcoming SE sites.

Comment: @deviantfan - Citation Needed

Comment: @deviantfan Please share your source...as it isn't obvious to us how you can backup your comment.

Comment: I agree with @Richard. This place is pretty friendly, particularly in SE terms!

Comment: Maybe the questions are being asked on behalf of someone else. Maybe the poster is just curious about how certain situations should be handled. Why is this important? As long as the questions are on topic, why do the questions have to pertain to an actual real event that the OP would have experienced?

Comment: I feel very disturbed that people think this is even an issue. _Ei incumbit probatio qui dicit, non qui negat_. Sure, it seems very unlikely but can you prove beyond a shadow of a doubt that he is fabricating his stories? Also, who cares if its fabricated? Surely, the answers will be of use to a lot of people.

Comment: @Xiagua that's the point: the answers are not _hugely_ useful. And it is an issue because they are wasting people's time and setting a dangerous precedent around "outrageous but improbable" stories

Comment: Given the last post was on Mar 16, maybe they had a spectacular St Patrick's Day scenario involving chocolate, the boss's daughter, their stock millions and God knows what else...

Comment: @deviantfan Some call SO the most un-friendly community on SE. Also physics, parenting, skeptics, and scifi.  I suspect the list is much, much longer than that, but generally anyone who is upset because their question was "wrongfully" closed, or who disagrees with an established rule, or who otherwise has a bone to pick with moderation (elected/appointed, or community action) tends to call that particular community "the most un-friendly" in the SE network.

Comment: For some reason the questions **vaguely** remind me of the TV series "The Office". They're ridiculous and I don't believe, in their current format, they would really offer any use to other users. I think this person's a troll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should anything be done about a user posting fake questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/should-anything-be-done-about-a-user-posting-fake-questions)

Comment: Damn, Mark! Now I 'm going to lose a whole day reading all of Hans' posts on all of our sites. Why spread them around? Couldn't he just have a blog or a podcast or a youtweet channel or somesuch?

Answer (score 36):

If posting questions like that is okay then we better change site name to Soap Opera Plots Stack Exchange. And change site topics accordingly.

In this case I would also recommend folks interested in questions and answers of real workplace matters start looking for some other place.

Coexistence of entertainment and real questions have been tried already at Stack Overflow and Programmers and ended in tears and I see no reason why it would be different here. ["The stuff spreads like kudzu..."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/31/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

> <sup>...Pretty soon the entire site is overrun with nothing but that kind of fun. And even if you grandfather a few in, you’ll enjoy neverending requests asking why their fun question or answer has to be removed, while this one over here is allowed to remain</sup>

Comment: "And even if you grandfather a few in" ... and yet, that is exactly what they do on SO, with a bazillion questions of "historical significance but not good on-topic questions". Perhaps SO could be renamed to Calvinball. :)

Comment: @MaskedMan: Historical lock is intended for the specific purpose of *halting* a particular question and *discouraging* imitators. It is precisely the opposite of "grandfathering in", and was designed from the ground up to stop exactly this class of questions.

Comment: @Nathan Sounds like grandfathering to me. Why haven't these questions been deleted if they are not meant to be on-topic or good questions on SO? If the question did not exist already and were to be asked now, it would be deleted. (Example: "what is the funniest comment in source code?" or whatever) Deleting such questions drastically reduces their visibility, and even people who can see it have no chance to use that as an excuse to imitate such questions.

Comment: @MaskedMan: Only people who deliberately misread the historical lock message can use those questions as excuses to ask similar questions, since the message *explicitly says* they are not models of good questions. In bold text, even. SO is perfectly willing to let people who willfully misread instructions ask their way straight into a q-block, since they will do so anyway. (Only some questions are histo-locked, even if they're quite old; if they're not all that notable, they're simply deleted.)

Comment: @Nathan ... and why aren't those questions deleted if they are not models of good questions? If "other" bad questions (that is, questions not modeled on "those" questions) are asked now, then those are deleted. That is the whole point of "grandfathering", or in other words, bad questions asked after X date will be deleted, but before X date, we will just put one "historical" note and keep them around.

Comment: @MaskedMan: There isn't really a fixed date. What matters is that the question somehow managed to do a decent job of creating something useful despite the dangerous formulation. Only unusually useful Q&A combos are kept. So: they aren't *deleted* because they're actually useful, quite dramatically so, and deleting is unpleasant in such cases; they aren't *left open* because that encourages imitators (or at least post facto rationalizing). Questions that are *actually* bad in all respects get shown the door no matter their age.

Comment: `And even if you grandfather a few in, you’ll enjoy neverending requests asking why their fun question or answer has to be removed, while this one over here is allowed to remain`: Hell yes. Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199302/131956

Answer (score 8):

Have you ever heard the expression, "When it rains, it pours"?

Honestly, everything up until 2/22 seems plausible. It isn't until the dating the boss' daughter post and the posts on other SEs that things look off. I'm not sure why some others find the idea of a young employee getting their car towed or wasting time on a bad joke so unbelievable. It's certainly a lot bad luck and poor decision making all at once but being unprepared for a meeting is hardly an extreme event.

I think the usefulness of these questions is more of an issue than their truthfulness. The two most suspicious Workplace questions are also off topic.

I'm not saying made up stories should be OK. I'm just not buying that it isn't possible for your car, bike, and phone to get broken in the same month.

Comment: Some say "you can't make this stuff up". I say "it sure looks like you can".

Comment: For the record, if I posted a list of every bad work decision and every weird situation I'd ever come across it would put this user's efforts to shame. To. Shame.

Comment: I don't see the point of this answer, or of saying 'Of the ten outrageous stories, the first five, taken in isolation, seem believable.' Clearly the earlier questions form part of a pattern with the later questions.