# Relevant question for thousands of German employees during the COVID-19 crisis was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, covid-19

*Disclaimer: I have written an upvoted answer to following question.*

This question was deleted by Community: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/155297/can-i-be-forced-to-take-yearly-vacation-due-to-corona-virus-outbreak-germany

The question is asking about general rules for vacation enforcement by the employer. It's not a special situation the OP is facing, therefore I wouldn't categorize it as legal advice. It contained a slightly off-topic portion by asking if there is a sign for being fired, but that could have been removed easily.

Was the user deleted or what was the reason for not just closing it but immediately deleting it? Are there special rules for COVID-19 questions?

Comment: Question looks fine to me... voting to undelete.

Comment: @Kilisi: I noticed that maybe the user was deleted, but I'm not sure, because normally I cannot see deleted questions.

Comment: I have no idea, just voting to undelete, anything else the mods can look into. I'm just a lowly user.

Comment: I cast the last undelete vote. Not sure why it was deleted, it looked like a perfectly valid question to me. In fact, my company is making people take previous year's remaining vacation right now, because of the reason I remarked on in a comment. It's certainly pertinent information to many people in germany right now.

Comment: digging into the timeline, it seems like the user that asked the question was destroyed by a moderator: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/155297/timeline an hour ago.

Comment: Yup, part of a SPAM attack.

Comment: Now it's closed without comment. Nice...

Comment: @gnat: I think your link is incorrect? This is about some other question?

Comment: @guest see comment from moderator above, it explains that removal reason is the same as in [linked answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4415/168) (spam attack)

Comment: @gnat: Yes, it's helpful. Maybe it could be more obvious in the deletion message? It's difficult to find the reason even if you look up possible reasons in the help center.

Comment: well a couple more reopen votes and it's back in action.

Comment: Edited the question cause it needed some work and reopened.

Comment: Good effort getting it undeleted and reopened. You had a solid answer as well.